# Running time of variant of Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

Consider the problem of finding the shortest-path distances from an origin vertex to all other vertices in a digraph. Normally in Dijkstra's algorithm, we visit the vertex whose shortest distance from the origin found so far is least, and that distance is set permanently as the shortest-path distance to that vertex. In the following algorithm, we maintain a queue of vertices to visit and we visit the oldest vertex in the queue but may revisit it later.

1. `shortest_distance_so_far` is a mapping on vertices, initially `0` for `v_origin` and `infinity` otherwise
2. `queue` is a queue containing (vertex, path length) pairs, initially only `(v_origin, 0)`
3. while `queue` is nonempty

   1. `v, k = dequeue(queue)`
   2. If `k > shortest_distance_so_far(v)`, skip to the next iteration
   3. for each outgoing edge from `v`, let `nbor` be the other vertex, and let `w` be the edge weight

      1. if `shortest_distance_so_far(v) + w < shortest_distance_so_far(nbor)`

         1. `shortest_distance_so_far(nbor) = shortest_distance_so_far(v) + w`
         2. `enqueue(queue, (nbor, shortest_distance_so_far(nbor)))`

My question is, does this have worst-case running time greater than the $O(|V|^2)$ running time of a simple implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm? We can assume the digraph is given as an adjacency list.

Comment: Empirically, on digraphs with $n$ vertices and edges from $i$ to $i+j$ with weight $j^2$, and with edges ordered by decreasing weight, running time divided by $n^2$ appears to increase while for the simple Dijkstra implementation it stays constant

Comment: ^ starting at vertex $1$